# Link a static library to a shared one during build?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries, libtool

I have a problem building a shared library with GCC/Linux. Currently this shared library is created with GCC/libtool option "-shared" and everything is fine.

Now there are two additional, static libraries (.a-files) that have to be added to this shared one since they provide some functionality that is required by the shared one. Adding these static libraries with option "-l" does not help, afterwards they are not part of the .so file.

So how can I force GCC/libtool to really add the code of these static libraries to the shared library?

Thanks!

Comment: For creating executables you can just add the full path of the static library to the building options of gcc, such as: `gcc -Wall -g live_mystuff.c -o my_app /usr/local/src/ffmpeg/libswscale/libswscale.a -lpthread -lbz2 -lm -lz -lfaac -lmp3lame -lx264 -lfaad ... ` It might work also for creating shared libraries. Try it.

Comment: How do you know they are "not part of the .so file"?

Comment: @fritzone: for executables that works without problems, I have to do it for a shared library

Comment: @Joachim: for two reasons: the shared library does not become bigger and when linking an executable against it, it complains about missing functions - the functions, that reside within the static libraries

Comment: How do you link the shared library? Please show complete command line, or makefile output.

Comment: @Joachim: Currently I build it using libttool:
    **libtool --mode=compile g++ -Wall -fPIC -shared -Wno-unused -D_REENTRANT** and
    **libtool --mode=link g++ -shared -rpath /usr/lib**
Now when I add a -lmystaticlib to one/both statements it seems to be ignored...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need `--whole-archive` linker option in this case to command the linker to include whole static libs' content into the shared lib.

```
g++ -shared sample.o -o libSample.so -Wl,-whole-archive -lmylib1.a -lmylib2.a -Wl,-no-whole-archive
```

From `man ld`:

> For each archive mentioned on the command line after the **--whole-archive** option, include every object file in the archive in the link, rather than searching the archive for the required object files.  This is normally used to turn an archive file into a shared library, forcing every object to be included in the resulting shared library.  This option may be used more than once.
>
> Two notes when using this option from gcc: First, gcc doesn't know about this option, so you have to use -Wl,-whole-archive.  Second, don't forget to use **-Wl,-no-whole-archive** after your list of archives, because gcc will add its own list of archives to your link and you may not want this flag to affect those as well.

Comment: on SunOS I had to use bot dashes after `-WL,`.

Answer (score 3):

You only need the **--whole-archive** parameter to *force* the linker to include the library, but it should be able to infer its own needs from unmatched symbols.

Ensure that any static libraries on the command-line come after their dependent object-files e.g.:

```
g++ -Wl,-E -g -pipe -O2 -pipe -fPIC  myobjectfile.o mystaticlibrary.a -shared -o mylib.so
```