# "relocation R_X86_64_32S against " linking Error

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm Trying to Link a static Library to a shared library , I'm Getting the Following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../libraries/log4cplus/liblog4cplus.a(fileappender.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../../../libraries/log4cplus/liblog4cplus.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But this worked on a 32bit machine without any such error. I tried adding The `-fPIC` flags manually to the Makefile that too didn't solve the problem

I tried the `-whole-archive` flag as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889941/link-a-static-library-to-a-shared-one-during-build) but with no success.

```
 
/usr/bin/ld: ../../../libraries/log4cplus/liblog4cplus.a(appenderattachableimpl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `vtable for log4cplus::spi::AppenderAttachable' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
../../../libraries/log4cplus/liblog4cplus.a(appenderattachableimpl.o): could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

#### Creation of liblog4cplus.a:

1. `unzip log4cplus-1.1.0.zip`
2. `./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-threads=yes`
3. `vi Makefile` and added -fPIC to CXXFLAGS and CFLAGS
4. `make`

#### Then for Compiling my shared library:

1. `g++ -frtti -w  -c -fPIC -I"Include_Directory" myfile.cpp`
2. `g++ -shared -fPIC -frtti -I"Include_Directory" -o mysofile.so myfile.o -Wl,--whole-archive "../../../libraries/log4cplus/liblog4cplus.a" -Wl,--no-whole-archive -ldl`

Comment: Can you paste the full command line? It would also be good if you indicated exactly what you mean by "Link a static Library to a shared library". Are you generating a shared library out of a static library?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis not really ...

Comment: For those asking in the future: sometimes this happens simply due to distro changes, and it can be fixed with a quick clean of the build directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do R\_X86\_64\_32S and R\_X86\_64\_64 relocation mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093547/what-do-r-x86-64-32s-and-r-x86-64-64-relocation-mean)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Assuming you are generating a shared library, most probably what happens is that the variant of `liblog4cplus.a` you are using wasn't compiled with `-fPIC`. In linux, you can confirm this by extracting the object files from the static library and [checking their relocations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340402/how-can-i-tell-with-something-like-objdump-if-an-object-file-has-been-built-wi):

```
ar -x liblog4cplus.a  
readelf --relocs fileappender.o | egrep '(GOT|PLT|JU?MP_SLOT)'
```

If the output is empty, then the static library is not position-independent and cannot be used to generate a shared object.

Since the static library contains object code which was already compiled, providing the -fPIC flag won't help.

You need to get ahold of a version of `liblog4cplus.a` compiled with `-fPIC` and use that one instead.

Comment: Hi fons, Thanks for your response and sorry for the late reply,your answer helped me to identify the problem .

Answer (score 12):

Add `-fPIC` at the end of `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAG`

Example:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall --std=c++11 -O3 -fPIC" )
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall -O3 -fPIC" )
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol , usually happens when LDFLAGS are set with hardening and CFLAGS not .
Maybe just user error:
If you are using -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld at link time, 
you also need to use -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 at compile time, and as you are compiling and linking at the same time, you need either both, or drop the -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld .
Common fixes :
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1304277#c3
https://github.com/rpmfusion/lxdream/blob/master/lxdream-0.9.1-implicit.patch

Answer (score 3):

I've got a similar error when installing FCL that needs CCD lib(libccd) like this:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libccd.a(ccd.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

I find that there is two different files named "libccd.a" :

1. /usr/local/lib/libccd.a
2. /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libccd.a

I solved the problem by removing the first file.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar problems when trying to link static compiled [fontconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/) and [expat](https://libexpat.github.io/) into a linux shared object:

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /3rdparty/fontconfig/lib/linux-x86_64/libfontconfig.a(fccfg.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/ld: /3rdparty/expat/lib/linux-x86_64/libexpat.a(xmlparse.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `stderr@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
[...]
```

This contrary to the fact that I was already passing `-fPIC` flags though `CFLAGS` variable, and other compilers/linkers variants (clang/lld) were perfectly working with the same build configuration. It ended up that these dependencies control position-independent code settings through despicable `autoconf` scripts and need `--with-pic` switch during build configuration on linux gcc/ld combination, and its lack probably overrides same the setting in `CFLAGS`. Pass the switch to `configure` script and the dependencies will be correctly compiled with `-fPIC`.