# Problems with libturbojpeg compiling love-0.9.2

Tags: linker, love2d, fpic

Just starting with Löve and I'm loving it!
I'm currently testing it under Ubuntu 14.04.

I was able to compile love 0.8.0 with no trouble, but I'm having problems compiling 0.9.2 from bitbucket.
It seems, I might have been [eaten by a grue...](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/Building_L%C3%96VE)

I got this error when linking, due to `libturbojpeg`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.a(libturbojpeg_la-turbojpeg.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

According to [this StackOverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768267/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-linking-error), it seems that the default libturbojpeg binary installed in Ubuntu via apt-get:

```
tomas@ubuntu:~/tomas/love/love-0.9.2-bitbucket$ dpkg -L libjpeg-turbo8-dev | grep libturbojpeg.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libturbojpeg.a
tomas@ubuntu:~/tomas/love/love-0.9.2-bitbucket$ dpkg -l libjpeg-turbo8-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                               Version                Architecture           Description
+++-==================================-======================-======================-=========================================================================
ii  libjpeg-turbo8-dev:amd64           1.3.0-0ubuntu2         amd64                  Development files for the IJG JPEG library
```

is not compiled with `-fPIC`, so I guess I'll have to get that its source code, recompile it with that option, and modify something in the build procedure of **löve** to point to the compiled one.

Am I going in the right direction, or may I have missed something?

Regards,
Tom

PD: I'm wondering why should this library need to be compiled with -fPIC in this specific case...

```
   -fPIC
       If supported for the target machine, emit position-independent code, suitable for dynamic linking and avoiding any limit on the size of the
       global offset table.  This option makes a difference on the m68k, PowerPC and SPARC.
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems updating to 0.9.2 tag made it work:

```
hg update 0.9.2
./platform/unix/automagic 
./configure
make
```

Check [here](https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/issue/1031/problems-with-libturbojpeg-compiling-love) for the issue on bitbucket.

> Alex Szpakowski:
>   This doesn't really help with the exact problem, but
>   LÖVE 0.9.2 doesn't depend on or link with libturbojpeg. The latest
>   code in the LÖVE repository is for 0.10.0, which has different
>   dependencies than 0.9.2 (and isn't complete/released yet.) If you want
>   to compile 0.9.2 for Linux (rather than using a .deb or PPA) you
>   should probably download the source from here:
>   https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/downloads/love-0.9.2-linux-src.tar.gz
>   , or update to the 0.9.2 tag in the Mercurial repository and run
>   automagic etc.