# relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against hidden symbol `pkgcontext' can not be used when making a shared object

Tags: cmake, pip, sudo, stderr, cmake-custom-command

I am getting this error when ever I try to use <`colcon build`>,

The error is as followss:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython3.12.a(import.o): relocation R_X86_64_TPOFF32 against hidden symbol `pkgcontext' can not be used when making a shared object
/usr/bin/ld: failed to set dynamic section sizes: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer__rosidl_generator_py.dir/build.make:109: rosidl_generator_py/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer/libspatio_temporal_voxel_layer__rosidl_generator_py.so] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:477: CMakeFiles/spatio_temporal_voxel_layer__rosidl_generator_py.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< spatio_temporal_voxel_layer [0.74s, exited with code 2]
```

I tried fixing the setup tools like using `pip install setuptools`, `pip install numpy`, I was not able to find the related Cmake files and modify them,
Please help me out in this

Comment: Is this a custom build of Python?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768267/relocation-r-x86-64-32s-against-linking-error